# How to conditionally unroll Hiccup data structures in Clojure

Tags: clojure, hiccup

How to elegantly render a conditonal list of menu items in Clojure's Hiccup-like data structures? My templating function ends up littered with calls to `into` and does not read naturally.

Desired result:

```
[:div.menu
  [:div.item "Home"]
  [:div.item "Private"]
  [:div.item "Private"]
  [:div.item "Public"]
```

If I put the private items in an `if`, I still need to unroll the returned vector, or deal with `nil`, so this doesn't work:

```
[:div.menu
  [:div.item "Home"]
  (if authenticated?
    [[:div.item "Private"]
     [:div.item "Private"]])
  [:div.item "Public"]]
```

I found I can use `(into [:div.menu] ...)` and pass in a list of items, but it's unwieldy and doesn't read naturally. I ended up with this expression:

```
(-> [:div.menu
      [:div.item "Home"]]
  (into (if (auth/authenticated?)
      [[:div.item "Private"]
       [:div.item "Private"]]
  (into [[:div.item "Public"]]))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out Hiccup treats lists differently from vectors, so you can return a () instead of a [] and have it unroll correctly:

```
[:div.menu
  [:div.item "Home"]
    (if authenticated?
      (list
        [:div.item "Private"]
        [:div.item "Private"]))
  [:div.item "Public"]]
```

Comment: The downside with this approach is that if you are using Reagent or a React-based library, you will get unique key warnings.